# I have this text file. I need to import these files in R but they have a different separators.What should i do?

Tags: r

I have a text file with separators such as `:` , `{` , `\t` `" "`. What code should I use to import the file in `R` so that I get organized data with no `NAs`

```
Time  DPIC5928.MV      PIC5929.MV      PIC5929.WSP      DPIC5928.WSP      DPIC5928.OutP      DPIC5930.MV      DPIC5930.WSP      DPIC5930.OutP      DPIC5932.MV      DPIC5932.WSP      DPIC5932.OutP      DPIC5934.MV      DPIC5934.WSP      DPIC5934.OutP      DPIC5936.MV      DPIC5936.WSP      DPIC5936.OutP      DPIC5938.MV      DPIC5938.WSP      DPIC5938.OutP      DPIC5942.MV      DPIC5942.WSP      DPIC5942.OutP      DPIC5944.MV      DPIC5944.WSP      DPIC5944.OutP      DPIC5951.MV      DPIC5951.WSP      DPIC5951.OutP      DPIC5953.MV      DPIC5953.WSP      DPIC5953.OutP      DPIC5956.MV      DPIC5956.WSP      DPIC5956.OutP      DPIC5958.MV      DPIC5958.WSP      DPIC5958.OutP      DPIC8571.MV      DPIC8571.WSP      DPIC8571.OutP      DPIC8574.MV      DPIC8574.WSP      DPIC8574.OutP      LIC5976.MV      LIC5976.WSP      LIC5976.OutP      LIC5977.MV      LIC5977.WSP      LIC5977.OutP      PIC5926.MV      PIC5926.WSP      PIC5926.OutP      PIC5929.OutP      PIC5931.MV      PIC5931.WSP      PIC5931.OutP      PIC5933.MV      PIC5933.WSP      PIC5933.OutP      PIC5935.MV      PIC5935.WSP      PIC5935.OutP      PIC5937.MV      PIC5937.WSP      PIC5937.OutP      PIC5939.MV      PIC5939.WSP      PIC5939.OutP      PIC5940.MV      PIC5940.WSP      PIC5940.OutP      PIC5941.MV      PIC5941.WSP      PIC5941.OutP      PIC5943.MV      PIC5943.WSP      PIC5943.OutP      PIC5950.MV      PIC5950.WSP      PIC5950.OutP      PIC5952.MV      PIC5952.WSP      PIC5952.OutP      PIC5955.MV      PIC5955.WSP      PIC5955.OutP      PIC5957.MV      PIC5957.WSP      PIC5957.OutP      PIC8573.MV      PIC8573.WSP      PIC8573.OutP      PIC8574.MV      PIC8574.WSP      PIC8574.OutP      FFIC8963.MV      FFIC8963.WSP      FFIC8963.OutP      FIC9901.MV      FIC9901.WSP      FIC9901.OutP      FIC9902.MV      FIC9902.WSP      FIC9902.OutP      FIC9903.MV      FIC9903.WSP      FIC9903.OutP      FIC9904.MV      FIC9904.WSP      FIC9904.OutP      FIC8535.MV      FIC8535.WSP      FIC8535.OutP      FIC8814.MV      FIC8814.WSP      FIC8814.OutP      FIC8816.MV      FIC8816.WSP      FIC8816.OutP      FIC8819.OutP      LIC8817.MV      LIC8817.WSP      LIC8817.OutP      LIC8822.MV      LIC8822.WSP      LIC8822.OutP      QIC8820.WSP      QIC8820.OutP      FIC8734.MV      FIC8734.WSP      FIC8734.OutP      FIC8735.MV      FIC8735.WSP      FIC8735.OutP      FIC8736.MV      FIC8736.WSP      FIC8736.OutP      FIC8739.MV      FIC8739.WSP      AIC8753.MV      FIC8521.MV      FIC8521.WSP      FIC8521.OutP      FIC8750.MV      FIC8750.WSP      FIC8750.OutP      QIC8741.MV      PIC8776.MV      PIC8776.WSP      PIC8776.OutP      FIC8739.OutP      LIC8737.MV      LIC8737.WSP      LIC8737.OutP      LIC8742.MV      LIC8742.WSP      LIC8742.OutP      PID01{CEAA8232-A2FE-4FD2-B05C-BAC3AED181E4}.MV      PID01{CEAA8232-A2FE-4FD2-B05C-BAC3AED181E4}.WSP      PID01{CEAA8232-A2FE-4FD2-B05C-BAC3AED181E4}.OutP      PID01{D6F1F46A-486B-43B2-B191-F9E3C2035A6A}.MV      PID01{D6F1F46A-486B-43B2-B191-F9E3C2035A6A}.WSP      PID01{D6F1F46A-486B-43B2-B191-F9E3C2035A6A}.OutP      FIC8536.MV      FIC8536.WSP      FIC8536.OutP      FIC8618.MV      FIC8618.WSP      FIC8618.OutP      FIC8637.MV      FIC8637.WSP      FIC8637.OutP      FIC8641.OutP      FIC8641.MV      FIC8641.WSP      AIC8701.MV      FIC8518.MV      FIC8518.WSP      FIC8518.OutP      FIC8651.MV      FIC8651.WSP      FIC8651.OutP      AIC8701.WSP      AIC8701.OutP      LIC8633.MV      LIC8633.WSP      LIC8633.OutP      LIC8639.MV      LIC8639.WSP      LIC8639.OutP      LIC8644.MV      LIC8644.WSP      LIC8644.OutP      AIC8832.WSP      AIC8832.OutP      FIC8819.MV      FIC8819.WSP      AIC8832.MV      FIC8519.MV      FIC8519.WSP      FIC8519.OutP      FIC8829.MV      FIC8829.WSP      FIC8829.OutP      QIC8643.OutP      LIC8830.MV      LIC8830.WSP      LIC8830.OutP      LIC8835.MV      LIC8835.WSP      LIC8835.OutP      LIC8849.MV      LIC8849.WSP      LIC8849.OutP      QIC8820.MV      PIC8855.MV      PIC8855.WSP      PIC8855.OutP      AIC8753.WSP      AIC8753.OutP      FIC_9115.MV      FIC_9115.WSP      FIC_9115.OutP      LIC8751.MV      LIC8751.WSP      LIC8751.OutP      LIC8763.MV      LIC8763.WSP      LIC8763.OutP      LIC8769.MV      LIC8769.WSP      LIC8769.OutP      PID01.MV      PID01.WSP      PID01.OutP      LIC8653.MV      LIC8653.WSP      LIC8653.OutP      LIC8688.MV      LIC8688.WSP      LIC8688.OutP      LIC8695.MV      LIC8695.WSP      LIC8695.OutP      FIC8505.MV      FIC8505.WSP      FIC8505.OutP      FIC8506.MV      FIC8506.WSP      FIC8506.OutP      FIC8507.MV      FIC8507.WSP      FIC8507.OutP      FIC_8972.MV      FIC_8972.WSP      FIC_8972.OutP      FIC_8973.MV      FIC_8973.WSP      FIC_8973.OutP      FIC_8974.MV      FIC_8974.WSP      FIC_8974.OutP      PIC6800.MV      PIC6800.WSP      PIC6800.OutP      PIC6801.MV      PIC6801.WSP      PIC6801.OutP      PIC6802.MV      PIC6802.WSP      PIC6802.OutP      PIC6803.MV      PIC6803.WSP      PIC6803.OutP      PIC6804.MV      PIC6804.WSP      PIC6804.OutP      PIC6805.MV      PIC6805.WSP      PIC6805.OutP      PIC6806.MV      PIC6806.WSP      PIC6806.OutP      PIC6807.MV      PIC6807.WSP      PIC6807.OutP      PIC6814.MV      PIC6814.WSP      PIC6814.OutP      PIC6815.MV      PIC6815.WSP      PIC6815.OutP      PIC6816.MV      PIC6816.WSP      PIC6816.OutP      PIC6817.MV      PIC6817.WSP      PIC6817.OutP      PIC6818.MV      PIC6818.WSP      PIC6818.OutP      FDIC_8112.MV      FDIC_8112.WSP      FDIC_8112.OutP      PDIC_8111.MV      PDIC_8111.WSP      PDIC_8111.OutP      QIC8741.WSP      QIC8741.OutP      SIC501MS.WSP      SIC501MS.OutP      PIC501PR.MV      PIC501PR.WSP      PIC501PR.OutP      PIC502PR.MV      PIC502PR.WSP      PIC502PR.OutP      PIC503PR.MV      PIC503PR.WSP      PIC503PR.OutP      SIC501MS.MV      PIC8708.MV      PIC8708.WSP      PIC8708.OutP      QIC8643.MV      QIC8643.WSP      FIC501ST.MV      FIC501ST.WSP      FIC501ST.OutP      PIC501HB.MV      PIC501HB.WSP      PIC501HB.OutP      HB01_Control:Measurement      HB01_Control:WorkingSetp      HB01_Control:Output      FIC502ST.MV      FIC502ST.WSP      FIC502ST.OutP      PIC502HB.MV      PIC502HB.WSP      PIC502HB.OutP      HB02_Control:Measurement      HB02_Control:WorkingSetp      HB02_Control:Output      DW01_Control:Measurement      DW01_Control:WorkingSetp      DW01_Control:Output      FIC503ST.MV      FIC503ST.WSP      FIC503ST.OutP      PIC503HB.MV      PIC503HB.OutP      HB03_Control:Measurement      HB03_Control:WorkingSetp      PIC503HB.WSP      HB03_Control:Output      CW01_Control:Gen_ControlMeas      CW01_Control:Gen_ControlSetpoint      MT01_Control:Measurement      MT01_Control:WorkingSetp      MT01_Control:Output      MT02_Control:Measurement      MT02_Control:WorkingSetp      MT02_Control:Output      SP01_Control:Measurement      SP01_Control:WorkingSetp      SP01_Control:Output      PL01_Control:Measurement      PL01_Control:WorkingSetp      PL01_Control:Output      CW1      CW2      BW2      CoatWt1      CW1_TBM      CW2_TBM      BW2_TBM      CoatWt1_TBM      MT03:Measurement      MT03:WorkingSetp      MT03:Output      BL Slice opening      ML Slice opening      TL Slice opening      TL Machine Consistency      ML Machine Consistency      BL Machine Consistency      Reel caliper      Reel caliper 2 sig      Reel BW      Reel BW 2 sig      Reel Moisture      Reel Moisture 2 sig      Base Moisture      Base Moisture 2 sig      FI_6769_MV:Value      FI_6767_MV:Value      BL Spray starch shower pressure      TL Spray starch shower pressure      {793B3E9F-FE5F-4456-8FE5-D643055ECDB3}{C3109258-F34C-41A2-AC35-DFC575EA8647}:Description      {793B3E9F-FE5F-4456-8FE5-D643055ECDB3}{C3109258-F34C-41A2-AC35-DFC575EA8647}:Name      {793B3E9F-FE5F-4456-8FE5-D643055ECDB3}{C3109258-F34C-41A2-AC35-DFC575EA8647}:Prefix      {793B3E9F-FE5F-4456-8FE5-D643055ECDB3}{C3109258-F34C-41A2-AC35-DFC575EA8647}:Unique      {793B3E9F-FE5F-4456-8FE5-D643055ECDB3}{D616E3C9-463A-4C9A-9F80-67EC6E61F7BB}:Description      {793B3E9F-FE5F-4456-8FE5-D643055ECDB3}{D616E3C9-463A-4C9A-9F80-67EC6E61F7BB}:Name      {793B3E9F-FE5F-4456-8FE5-D643055ECDB3}{D616E3C9-463A-4C9A-9F80-67EC6E61F7BB}:Prefix      {793B3E9F-FE5F-4456-8FE5-D643055ECDB3}{D616E3C9-463A-4C9A-9F80-67EC6E61F7BB}:Unique      PM5 QCS AOS:Upload_NameResolve      PM5 QCS AOS:Upload_ObsoleteHandling      {9DD9FFF8-4BD3-4AE6-8CA6-41357FD2AF41}:ReelSpeed      
43193 0.1495079 0.1479362 0.1589434 0.15 3.834523 0.1695125 0.17 95.19784 0.1511559 0.15 33.98672 0.2560616 0.22 100 0.1800412 0.15 100 0.3825437 0.3825437 50 0.1532921 0.15 33.46741 0.2009003 0.2 26.26141 0.1977874 0.2 24.17637 0.2546578 0.25 57.5904 0.2015717 0.2 27.18404 0.2014038 0.2 48.43469 0.1929351 0.2 17.03252 0.1509728 0.15 21.20977 38.84336 40 66.75614 48.68857 35 0 0.4502937 0.45 72.05853 26.99384 0.8496987 0.85 28.43296 0.1853208 0.1907321 14.36297 1.000153 1 45.00053 0 0 100 0 0 0 2.50309 2.5 53.72046 1.3019 1.303087 60.31203 1.696269 1.694013 77.33348 0.4402991 0.4364026 42.74618 0.3752956 0.4364026 29.86913 0.4373236 0.4373236 40.05509 0.435874 0.4364026 58.43704 1.691844 1.694013 75.48428 1.301061 0.2 0 19.40642 21.43866 100 0 0 0 5.822461 5.827276 24.93211 3.791867 3.783897 15.7209 0 0 0 1120.836 1153.287 34.25884 734.5312 770.8467 24.03729 1077.297 1083.217 33.16354 41.73289 46.90929 47 81.63694 41.87839 42 46.42873 3.42 81.73021 1371.023 1353.708 30.78292 409.8878 415.3788 23.30231 622.324 610.6066 25.50177 4.12579 4 7.156481 1.31722 1.311249 458.6343 3.912064 3.8 31.79155 3.005386 2.108125 2.1 90.59792 15.94046 45.16365 45 33.37167 53.19448 53 43.90256 85.98917 85.98917 30 4.151522 4.151522 65 355.816 357.752 26.6184 0 0 1.720833 372.8694 359.2631 21.10731 26.25917 3.995197 4 6.073762 0.5890746 0.5871091 532.6077 3.821355 3.8 43.3708 6.073762 0 74.11154 74.11154 33 32.99458 33 83.59292 38.03616 38 45.19979 7.5 0 3.547093 3.5 7.101396 4.26569 4.257165 1036.007 3.810575 3.8 27.64906 53.40652 99.22026 97.7 5 84.8661 85 37.2459 85.4551 85 12.11832 3.408331 1.435294 3.5 0 4 100 2.250706 0 50 96.0174 95 5 94.91112 95 39.35786 92.84047 93 31.37964 0.1336996 0.01841955 15.44655 100 97 5 92.55512 92 23.97238 80.18463 80 68.43712 0 0 450 0 0 450 0.00608835 0.00608835 450 2.000478 2 9.544873 3.024949 3.024949 9.367188 1.995669 2 11.51845 -14.18692 -14.18692 35 -4.142063 -4.142063 18 -19.5613 -19.5613 68 -2.290532 -2.290532 40 0 0 25 -1.129013 -1.129013 70.1738 -3.528526 -3.528526 28.88786 -23.32425 -23.5 48.23544 -1.300987 -1.3 31.49143 -3.507744 -3.5 55.42409 -3.596397 -3.6 52.57065 -23.91333 -24 47.49361 -13.48943 -13.5 83.48131 10.60442 10.6 119.8982 119.7833 119.9093 73.79432 3 51.86765 325 0 0.4373236 0.4362668 36.52502 1.301061 1.30054 82.19334 0.205005 0.2119379 23.89397 325.5024 3.128862 3.1 48.74351 3.181381 3.2 2093.937 2100 1134.719 1313.75 1313.727 1361.261 1.049933 1.05 43.7909 3458.044 3458.549 1137.406 1326.962 1324.842 1262.4 1.050863 1.05 44.16141 201.7404 202 74.52758 2291.229 2300 847.2041 1304.776 1224.864 1.048892 1.05 1305.989 43.53297 179.9036 180.184 6.764023 6.8 18.17778 10.79882 10.8 26.54163 325.5024 325 0 7841.806 7859.604 257.9037 196.1229 179.9422 201.8355 23.71411 194.2371 179.8192 201.288 21.27375 37.99402 38 4.325263 16.82962 19.19163 20.9366 3.5 3.160689 3.1 247.9063 2.932807 210.3233 3.483418 6.751792 0.3555263 10.84585 0.5188838 0.0265507 0.1210355 0.4968337 0.5178912 Do not change this name QC OPC  0  PM5 QCS AOS  1 0 0 338.5225 
43198 0.1457847 0.1479362 0.1606327 0.15 3.575869 0.1695125 0.17 94.95773 0.1522698 0.15 34.10299 0.2594797 0.22 100 0.1875944 0.15 100 0.3862974 0.3862974 50 0.1573968 0.15 32.97968 0.1998169 0.2 26.2937 0.2117189 0.2 25.52248 0.253193 0.25 59.57039 0.2042115 0.2 28.04637 0.2096437 0.2 47.98128 0.1977874 0.2 16.92545 0.1509728 0.15 21.17176 38.46799 40 67.14131 48.74202 35 0 0.4502937 0.45 72.05324 27.23969 0.8496987 0.85 28.43373 0.1873045 0.1927592 14.42903 1.000153 1 44.92222 0 0 100 0 0 0 2.501335 2.5 53.76677 1.3019 1.300113 60.18166 1.694514 1.690146 77.06172 0.4402991 0.4291099 42.45632 0.3752956 0.4291099 30.31659 0.4373236 0.4373236 40.05509 0.435874 0.4291099 58.3126 1.690089 1.690146 75.25339 1.302968 0.2 0 19.85809 21.43866 100 0 0 0 5.831235 5.820159 24.91769 3.791867 3.785457 15.71526 0 0 0 1175.769 1161.359 33.90309 784.4663 776.9675 23.85585 1075.21 1076.938 33.0387 41.67397 46.83146 47 81.90712 42.0676 42 46.02317 3.42 80.69348 1371.023 1336.185 30.72288 424.2008 413.3856 22.51829 621.5305 607.738 25.30539 4.029111 4 7.156481 1.312306 1.309606 458.8371 3.900236 3.8 31.77778 3.015213 2.099336 2.1 90.38475 15.74042 45.16365 45 33.14186 53.08156 53 44.2845 86.02731 86.02731 30 4.142275 4.142275 65 356.2371 357.0385 26.63129 0 0 1.720833 369.8482 357.9847 20.98874 26.26011 3.996845 4 6.07657 0.5918517 0.588188 532.7635 3.821491 3.8 43.35455 6.07657 0 73.88571 73.88571 33 32.99458 33 83.59258 37.85 38 45.97904 7.5 0 3.545539 3.5 7.101396 4.271672 4.25875 1036.532 3.815545 3.8 27.65266 53.65913 99.33624 97.7 5 84.8661 85 37.33266 85.49783 85 12.01125 3.362097 1.430808 3.5 0 4 100 1.297017 0 50 95.97925 95 5 94.98589 95 39.36162 93.13802 93 30.99435 0.1336996 0.01841955 15.30252 100 97 5 92.78401 92 23.87472 80.52186 80 68.07832 0 0 450 0 0 450 0.003097581 0.003097581 450 2.003095 2 9.540345 3.024949 3.024949 9.367188 2.007439 2 11.51807 -14.05447 -14.05447 35 -4.217594 -4.217594 18 -19.59869 -19.59869 68 -2.290532 -2.290532 40 0 0 25 -1.155716 -1.155716 70.1738 -3.563272 -3.563272 28.88786 -23.25803 -23.5 48.25675 -1.32769 -1.3 31.49167 -3.507744 -3.5 55.42428 -3.571831 -3.6 52.5386 -23.99451 -24 47.47 -13.48943 -13.5 83.49519 10.61687 10.6 119.9275 119.9741 119.9361 73.77648 3 51.9568 325 0 0.4355688 0.4265491 36.28869 1.302968 1.300124 82.05472 0.2067598 0.2129714 23.96405 325.3796 3.135821 3.1 49.30225 3.192862 3.2 2097.085 2100 1134.645 1315.915 1313.812 1360.265 1.050328 1.05 43.79374 3455.126 3459.774 1137.765 1321.926 1324.715 1263.823 1.048939 1.05 44.15717 201.7846 202 74.529 2290.055 2300 847.4266 1304.991 1224.869 1.049725 1.05 1306.107 43.53691 179.9976 180.184 6.747869 6.8 17.77288 10.79716 10.8 26.53314 325.3796 325 0 7840.404 7860.708 257.9285 196.1229 179.9422 201.8355 23.71411 194.4081 179.9584 201.4059 22.84422 38.01403 38 4.346355 16.78694 19.2061 20.99825 3.5 3.160689 3.1 247.9063 2.932807 210.3233 3.483418 6.751792 0.3555263 10.84585 0.5188838 0.0265507 0.1736773 0.4968337 0.519646 Do not change this name QC OPC  0  PM5 QCS AOS  1 0 0 338.3947 
43203 0.1525597 0.1479362 0.1597394 0.15 3.712809 0.1702907 0.17 96.38646 0.1522698 0.15 34.1968 0.2590524 0.22 100 0.1887236 0.15 100 0.3870298 0.3870298 50 0.1517815 0.15 33.34224 0.197528 0.2 26.31971 0.2041657 0.2 25.982 0.2404059 0.25 56.5317 0.2049439 0.2 27.63006 0.2036469 0.2 47.93297 0.2042115 0.2 17.99834 0.1502098 0.15 21.16625 38.99443 40 67.18616 48.77713 35 0 0.4502937 0.45 72.05103 27.21195 0.851606 0.85 28.42655 0.1873045 0.1926994 14.43674 0.9983978 1 44.99259 0 0 100 0 0 0 2.50309 2.5 53.7499 1.299992 1.301297 60.29487 1.690623 1.692082 77.40108 0.4402991 0.4263423 42.26391 0.3733883 0.4261371 30.92907 0.4355688 0.4355688 40.05509 0.4341192 0.4261371 58.18727 1.690089 1.692082 75.44739 1.302968 0.2 0 19.56054 21.07911 100 0 0 0 5.831235 5.821157 24.91544 3.801785 3.783737 15.70828 0 0 0 1199.908 1174.454 33.76589 819.2569 786.4325 23.28536 1075.365 1089.2 33.29936 41.61496 46.6804 47 83.35072 42.0676 42 46.17371 3.42 79.89582 1368.917 1343.543 30.73645 418.1582 406.0238 21.89946 613.2601 611.4577 25.41173 3.898342 4 7.156481 1.306538 1.309781 459.6348 3.90522 3.8 31.76947 3.035508 2.101625 2.1 90.33607 16.0761 45.16365 45 33.12307 52.97017 53 44.66013 86.02731 86.02731 30 4.144564 4.144564 65 356.7132 357.181 26.64726 0 0 1.720833 369.1463 356.0119 20.88435 26.26882 3.995197 4 6.07657 0.5918517 0.5871091 533.6 3.811109 3.8 43.3853 6.07657 0 73.88571 73.88571 33 32.99458 33 83.37078 37.92477 38 45.70155 7.5 0 3.547503 3.5 7.101396 4.26569 4.256393 1036.83 3.81728 3.8 27.65173 52.81482 99.26147 97.7 5 84.8661 85 37.29698 85.64584 85 11.89976 3.339529 1.435294 3.5 0 4 100 1.297017 0 50 96.05249 95 5 94.87297 95 39.4752 92.91371 93 31.14303 0.1336996 0.01841955 15.15404 100 97 5 92.78401 92 23.79085 80.6775 80 67.73447 0 0 450 0 0 450 0.003097581 0.003097581 450 2.014602 2 9.539576 3.024949 3.024949 9.367188 2.008351 2 11.51587 -14.29053 -14.29053 35 -4.254215 -4.254215 18 -19.59869 -19.59869 68 -2.335149 -2.335149 40 0 0 25 -1.155716 -1.155716 70.1738 -3.614161 -3.614161 28.88786 -23.50851 -23.5 48.2235 -1.300987 -1.3 31.49043 -3.507744 -3.5 55.42264 -3.571831 -3.6 52.54427 -24.07248 -24 47.44129 -13.46487 -13.5 83.51204 10.63017 10.6 119.8518 119.9588 119.8762 73.73589 3 52.7874 325 0 0
```

Comment: Perhaps you could improve your question by being less verbose and by better formatting your data. It's not clear what comes from which file.

Comment: Okay @RomanLuštrik. I have a text file with separators as ":" , "{" , "\t" " ". What code should I use to import the file in R so that I get organized data with no "NAs"

Comment: You will have to read each line and custom parse it. I don't thinks there is no blackbox way of doing this.

Comment: @Manas, is it possible for you to replace all delimiter(: { \t " " )  with "\t" using any text editor like Notepad++, Vim etc?, if it is then we can do it and then import in R.